# Visual C++ constexpr Hints

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17

Visual C++ is notorious for ignoring constexpr function qualifiers unless absolutely required. Look at the following function:

```
constexpr int multiply(int l, int r) noexcept
{
    return l * r;
}
```

According to the standard, Visual C++ is completely allowed to not evaluate the rvalue at compile-time:

```
auto three_times_four = multiply(3, 4);
```

The workaround I've been using is this ugly force:

```
constexpr auto constexpr_three_times_four = ;
auto not_constexpr_three_times_four = constexpr_three_times_four;
// use not_constexpr_three_times_four in non-constexpr contexts

// alternatively:
template<auto val>
inline constexpr auto ensure_constexpr = val;
auto not_constexpr_three_times_four = ensure_constexpr<multiply(3, 4)>;
```

Is there a way I can hint to the compiler that these things should be evaluated at compile-time?

I'm especially annoyed with the following:

```
namespace l
{
    constexpr ::std::uint32_t operator""_crc32(const char * p, ::std::size_t const size) noexcept
    {
        return crc32(p);
    }
}
//...
using namespace l;
search("foo"_crc32);//You don't want to evaluate this at runtime? too bad.
```

So, what can I do to hint the compiler in this case and avoid these ugly fixes?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217759/discussion-on-question-by-super-developer-visual-c-constexpr-hints).

Answer (score 6):

There is no mechanism to "hint" to the compiler (any compiler) that a `constexpr` function "should" be called at compile-time. That's not what `constexpr` is *for*. It's not a tool for speeding up execution of code. It's a tool for allowing you to do computations that *have* to be done at compile-time.

C++20 allows functions to be designated `consteval`, which ensures that the function must be executed within a constant expression. But even that feature isn't for performance; it's there so that they can add new features of the language (like reflection values) that can only exist at compile time and cannot leak into runtime code.

C++20's `constinit` allows you to declare non-constant expression variables whose initializer is required to be a constant expression. That's the closest C++ gets to `constexpr`-as-a-performance-feature.

But otherwise, if the compiler's higher optimization levels aren't calling those functions at compile time, then that's how the compiler has chosen to implement the feature.

Comment: Seeing that `constinit` was added to the language, I assume there is some implicit understanding that this "optimization" should (or should've) exist(ed). I suppose I'll just need to wait until compilers are done with their C++20 implementation and stick with `ensure_constexpr` for now.